# How is throughput calculated in Jmeter in case of multiple Users

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am running a sampler request with 1 VUser and using aggregate report as a Listener while have only 1 Vuser eg : [image: 1Userthread] and running the test i get the throughput as 2.9/sec as shown in the image [image: 2.9/sec] . I know throughtput is calculated as
Throughput = (number of requests) / (average * number of requests)
=1/(343*1) = 0.00291545 ms = 2.9Sec

But when i run the test with 2 threads [image: 2Threads]
I get the throughtput as 2.5/sec [image: 2.5 /sec]
Using the above formula for throughput (2)/(505*2) =0.0019802 which is not equal to throughput shown in the report .
How is Throughput calculated when the Number of users are increased Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

> I know throughtput is calculated as Throughput = (number of requests) / (average * number of requests) =1/(343*1) = 0.00291545 ms = 2.9Sec

I think what you "know" is not correct. According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

So you should divide the total number of requests by your test duration as this is [what JMeter does under the hood](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/c7279348335b820c35ee570462cb2e0b4eb1c370/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java#L201).

More information: [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)